# Сайт по IP сервера

Tags: nginx, centos

Как сменить сайт, который открывается по *IP* сервера?

Открывается сайт, который я первым добавил.

Дистрибутив: *CentOS 6.6*

Comment: Как у вас в тэгах одновременно оказались `apache` и `nginx`? Уточните какой именно сервер вы используете.

Comment: Сервер nginx, с апачем я ошибся

Answer (score 2, accepted):

согласно [документации](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/server_names.html), по умолчанию, т.е. если не найден подходящий `server` с `server_name`, совпадающим с запросом, будет использоваться первый встреченный в конфигурации `server`:

- у которого указано `default_server` в директиве `listen`
- либо, если `default_server` не определён, то нет директивы `server_name`
- либо среди имён присутствует «некорректное» имя типа `_` или `--`, или что-либо подобное.

есть специальное обозначение для имени — `""` — означает, что этот `server` будет использован, если в *http-запросе* не передано поле `host`.

также можно использовать в качестве `server_name` не только [`fqdn`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/FQDN), но и *ip-адрес*.

пример:

```
server {
  ...
  server_name 10.0.0.1 "";
  ...
}
server {
  ...
  server_name 192.168.0.1 _;
  ...
}
```

первый из `server`-ов будет использован при запросах вида `http://10.0.0.1/...`, либо если не передан заголовок `host`.

второй из `server`ов будет использован при запросах вида `http://192.168.0.1`, либо при произвольных именах вида `http://sample.server` (если, конечно, эти запросы смогут «добраться» до *nginx-а*).

Answer (score 2):

У вас есть два способа явно указать тот сайт, который будет открываться по IP-адресу:

- добавить параметр `default_server` в директиву `listen`;
- или добавить IP-адрес сервера в директиву `server_name`.

В первом случае указанный сайт будет открываться при любом запросе с непонятным значением заголовка `Host` - во втором же случае поведение по умолчанию на изменится, изменится лишь поведение при открытии страниц через IP-адрес.